# Momentary Black Screen on PC When Using Graphics-Intensive Apps

Tags: windows-10, drivers, troubleshooting, gaming, tv

I've been having a small issue thats really bothering me with my newly built PC. When I do something like minimize Edge, open the Netflix app from the windows store, close the Netflix app, etc, it causes the screen of my 4K tv to go black for just a second before continuing as normal. This can be seen in the link I've added. I've tried a number of things and found the following results.

1. I tried changing the scaling from 225% to 100%, no effect.
2. I tried using another tv, no problems at all were seen on the other tv, implying the problem is with the tv.
3. I tried reducing the refresh rate of the tv from 60 to 30 Hz, no effect.
4. I tried uninstalling the graphics driver, restarting, then reinstalling. No change.
5. I tried turning off game mode, no change, so I turned it back on.
6. I tried repeating the steps while using Remote Desktop. Interestingly, my laptop displayed these fine but my tv still flashed black while sitting on the sign in page as it does when you’re signed into Remote Desktop.

I'm wondering if there is some kind of conflict between two apps or something that might affect the display settings but I haven't seen anything that would explain this. Either way, it seems like the issue happens whenever there is a very quick change to what needs to be displayed, such as you'd have when minimizing Netflix.

Video: https://vimeo.com/397358484

Comment: Have you setup your TV to use game mode? Most new tv's have lots of processing which will make small screen changes become really noticable.

Comment: @LPChip Yeah unfortunately it was already in game mode, I added a little information to the question to cover a couple more things I’ve tried to get this fixed.